# Username to Logon to Vigor Draytek 2950

Tags: configuration, router, login, draytek, vigor

I have a dual-wan [DrayTek Vigor 2950](http://www.draytek.com/user/PdInfoDetail.php?Id=42) router and it's working really really good! The only thing that bothers me, without being a huge problem, is that I can't configure a user name to connect to the router's configuration page. It's very easy to set a password, but after looking everywhere in the user's guide and on the web, I still stay without answers. Does anyone have an idea, how I could resolve that case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard the new firmware for the Vigor 2950 series should be integrating the option of user setup. Different kind of rights, etc...
But that kind of Firmware update will require a reconfiguration of the system I assume.
Anyway, I would leave it the way it is if it works! The best routers in my opinion!

Comment: I just received an update from Draytek containing the possibility to change the username. Thank you for your advice Ron.

Answer (score 2):

You can't configure the username on the Vigor 2950. It's always "admin". In effect there is no username, and in fact if you telnet to it rather than using the web interface you'll find it doesn't even ask you for a username.

Good routers, aren't they :-)

JR

Comment: So it has to stay this way, and there's nothing I can do about it? Ok, it's actually better without having to type a user name! Thanks.
P.S.: Excellent Router!